# Best way to request user input without stalling the GUI?

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a simple question and answer type program, with a bit of code like this:

```
  private void AskQuestion(Question q)
        {
            questionbox.Text = q.GetQuestion();
            answering = true;

            while (answering == true)
            {

            }

                if (q.GetQuestion() == answerbox.Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("well done");
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("nope");
                }

        }
```

answering is just a toggle that i have so the program doesn't test for the answer until the user has put the answer in and clicked a button.

i have a button for user to click, which switches it over to false:

```
private void Answer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            answering = false; 
        }
```

The idea is that the while loop pauses the program and exits when the user has answered the question, but it just freezes the whole thing.

I tried slowing it down with thread sleeping, then I went for a timer watching the variable, tried it on a new thread, but the threads wouldn't talk to each other, so I'm in this silly situation where I'm stuck.

Please help programmers, and suggest a strategy for me here?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to pause your program. Do you want to do other stuff while waiting for the user?

Comment: it has to wait for the user to enter an a question before it checks if its correct, so theres no point in moving on to the next bit of code, the comparrison, before the user has put it into a text box. which is when the bool is set to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just store the Question in a field and put the Answer logic in the `Answer_Click`

```
private Question _currentQuestion;

private void AskQuestion(Question q)
{
    _currentQuestion = q.GetQuestion();
    questionbox.Text =_currentQuestion;
}

private void Answer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (_currentQuestion != null)
   {
      if (_currentQuestion == answerbox.Text)
      {
          MessageBox.Show("well done");
      }

      else
      {
          MessageBox.Show("nope");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hey = true;
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AskQuestion));
            thread.Start();
        }

        bool hey;
        void AskQuestion()
        {
            while (hey)
            { 

            }
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }

        private void answer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hey = false;
        }
```

This shows MessageBox when answer_Click() pressed. It doesn't freeze.